# Drupal Commerce stop titles of variations replacing product title

Tags: 7, commerce

I am new to [Drupal Commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) and am using [Commerce Kickstart 2](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

When I make variations the currently selected variation is replacing the title of the product. I would like the product to have one title that remains fixed regardless of what variation is selected. I'm pretty sure I had managed to set this up in a product/variation combination I had set up before, but now can't find where to set this up.